# how do you point 'screen_function' to a function in the same class?

Tags: plugins, buddypress, profiles

In a plugin class, I'm successfully creating a new tab on a Member page using:

```
    bp_core_new_nav_item( array(
    'name' => __( 'MyTab', 'bp' ),
    'slug' => 'mytab',
    'position' => 200,
    'screen_function' => array( $this, 'mytab_screen' ),
    'default_subnav_slug' => 'mytab'
) );
```

The problem appears when you click the tab.
The function is found - this Warning *DOES NOT* appear:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback etc
```

But the function is not called and you end up on the 
'It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for.' page.

Am I using the correct approach to point 'screen_function'  to a public function in the same class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the correct approach.

The problem was in the function mytab_screen()
I wasn't using 'array' for the 2nd parameter in the add_action for the template call.

Nothing fancy, just sloppiness.